# Why we have to define variable dp = [0] * (n+1) just to set its variable equal to 0( In Dynamic Programming)

Tags: python, algorithm, variables

I have some questions about someone define: `dp = [0] * (n + 1)` just to set the variable equal to 0, what does it suppose to do?

Comment: It generates a list of *n+1* items, all set to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python you can multiply a list and tuple with an integer *n*. It will then generate a list or tuple with a length *l×n* with *l* the length of the given list/tuple. It will repeat the elements in that collection, like:

```
>>> [1,4,2,5]*3
[1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 5]
>>> (1,4,2,5)*3
(1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 5)
```

Since here the given list is a singleton, you thus construct a list with length `n+1` where each element is `0`, like:

```
>>> [0] * (5 + 1)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

When you multiply a list/tuple with an integer, the *references* of the items are coped. You thus do *not* make a "deep copy" of the values. Since `int`s are immutable, that does not matter. But if the elements are lists for example, you did not make copies of that list, you made a list where you referenced the same list multiple times.

Comment: thanks for helping me, i've studied python in a short time so that some fields is quite hard to know. Do you have some tips to learn it quickly and effectively ?

Comment: One of the way to learn python quickly and effectively is [Hackerearth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/python/getting-started/). This would atleast brush up your basics, rest is all about practice.